# Qt: How do I make my label be updated from a combobox from a database?

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt, qt5

I'm making a form filling program and I wanted to make a label that when the user picks something from a combobox (name of a person) the address gets filled out in the label. I'm using an sqllite database.
The form looks like  this:
[Screenshot of how the form is supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FltD7.png)
This is my code for now. The labels name is laAddress

```
#include "ui_izdavanje_recepta.h"
#include <QDate>

Izdavanje_recepta::Izdavanje_recepta(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Izdavanje_recepta)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    modelCBime = new QSqlQueryModel;
    modelCBime->setQuery("SELECT idPacijent, ime FROM Pacijent");
    ui->imePacCB->setModel(modelCBime);
    ui->imePacCB->setModelColumn(1);


    modelCBkod = new QSqlQueryModel;
    modelCBkod->setQuery("SELECT idDoktor,ime FROM Doktor");
    ui->SifraDoktoraCB->setModel(modelCBkod);
    ui->SifraDoktoraCB->setModelColumn(0);


    QDate cd = QDate::currentDate();
    ui->laDatum->setText(cd.toString("d. M. yyyy"));    
}

Izdavanje_recepta::~Izdavanje_recepta()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Izdavanje_recepta::on_imePacCB_activated(const QString &arg1)
{

}


void Izdavanje_recepta::on_imePacCB_activated(int index)
{
 QSqlRecord record=modelCBime->record();
 spID = modelCBime->record(index).value("idPacijent").toInt(); //this grabs the id which will later on be put into the database 
}`
```

Comment: something like ui->laAddress->setText(address)?

Comment: yes, I tried something like that and sadly it did not work

Comment: why didn't it work?

Comment: I don't think you have posted enough code for anyone to help you. There is no reason that `ui->laAddress->setText(address)` wouldn't work unless the address is not correct. So, we information on how you expect to lookup the address or how you are doing that now.